# Setting a Grid inside a shapefile in r

Tags: coordinate-system, r, spatial-database

I am trying to crate a grid inside a shapefile, something like this. However, I am unable to generate such grid. I was wondering if anyone has an idea on how to accomplish this.

Here is my code -

```
WWWL.Shape<- readOGR("E:/Juan Arango", "WWL_Commerce_OK")
WWWL.Shape
plot(WWWL.Shape)
proj4string(WWWL.Shape)

bb <- bbox(WWWL.Shape)
cs <- c(3.28084, 3.28084)*6000  # cell size 
cc <- bb[, 1] + (cs/2)  # cell offset
cd <- ceiling(diff(t(bb))/cs)  # number of cells per direction
grd <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset=cc, cellsize=cs, cells.dim=cd)
grd
sp_grd <- SpatialGridDataFrame(grd,
                               data=data.frame(id=1:prod(cd)),
                               proj4string=CRS(proj4string(WWWL.Shape)))
plot(sp_grd)
```

Output of WWWL.Shape

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 334367, 334498.7, 4088915, 4089057  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 1
names       : Id 
min values  :  0 
max values  :  0
```

Output `plot(sp_grid)`
[image]

What I am hopping to get is something that looks like this

[image]

Comment: fwiw, use raster instead, it's vastly more powerful and user-friendly than sp for grids - it works with sp structures, but it's not "of sp structures" - so you end up knowing two systems, but it's worthwhile.

Comment: That purple square looks like a grid - what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Spacedman I was hopping to get the actual grid inside the shapefile (something that looks more like the image that I just added on the original post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to define a cell size of 19685.04 in an extent that is too small. In fact, your extent is so small that at a 10m cell resolution there are still only 182 cells. Here is a quick way to create a SpatialPixelsDataFrame or SpatialGridDataFrame object.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

cs = 10 # Raster cell size

# Create extent and coerce to SpatialPolygons 
e <- as( raster::extent(334367, 334498.7, 4088915, 4089057), "SpatialPolygons")
  proj4string(e) <- "+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
    class(e)
    plot(e)

# Create raster from defined extent
r <- raster(e, resolution = cs)
  r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
  plot(r)
cat("\n", "Number of cells in raster: ", ncell(r), "\n")  

# Coerce to SpatialPixelsDataFrame
r <- as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
  class(r)

# Plot cell boundaries (grid) and SpatialPixelsDataFrame raster
plot( as(r, "SpatialPolygons") )
plot(r)
```